# laravel Auth:check() fails

Tags: php, laravel, twig

I´m using in laravel the twigbridge, but when I verified if auth don´t recognized it.

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% if (Auth::check()) %}
                        <li><a href="{{ urlFor('logout') }}">Salir</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="{{ urlFor('login') }}">Entrar</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

the line 32 is (Auth::check())

Here the error getting

```
An opened parenthesis is not properly closed. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("punctuation" expected with value ")") in "admin/base" at line 32
```

Comment: Try `{% if Auth::check() %}`, I am not sure how twig handles Laravel's facades.

Comment: I solved it with Auth.check()

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {% if (Auth.check()) %}
            <li><a href="{{ urlFor('logout') }}">Salir</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="{{ urlFor('login') }}">Entrar</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The important part being `Auth.check()` not `::`